# Как размапить array of objects если в нем есть одинаковие ключи?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, map

**Как достать значения из массива объектов если ключи повторяются как в примере ниже?**

```js
  const myArray = [
       {id: 1, person: { name: "Joe" }, company:{name: "PNG inc."}},
        {id: 2, person: { name: "John" }, company:{name: "Google"}},
        {id: 3, person: { name: "Joe" }, company:{name: "OBS"}}
     ];

     const results = myArray.map(({id, person: { name }}) => ({id, name}));
     
     console.log(results)
```

> Как в array **results** добавить **company.name** и **person.name** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myArray = [
  { id: 1, person: { name: "Joe" }, company: { name: "PNG inc." } },
  { id: 2, person: { name: "John" }, company: { name: "Google" } },
  { id: 3, person: { name: "Joe" }, company: { name: "OBS" } }
];

const results = myArray.map(({ id, person: { name: person }, company: { name: company } }) => ({ id, person, company }));
console.log(results)
```

Comment: Спасибо! супер, ответ. Не знал что так можно.

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn, вот здесь интересный пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/59425726/12915495 там вообще черт голову сломит

Answer (score 3):

```js
const myArray = [{
    id: 1,
    person: { name: "Joe" },
    company: { name: "PNG inc." }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    person: { name: "John" },
    company: { name: "Google" }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    person: { name: "Joe" },
    company: { name: "OBS" }
  }
];

const results = myArray.map(item => { return {
  id: item.id,
  person: item.person.name,
  company: item.company.name
}; });

console.log(results)
```

Comment: ООо. спасибо за оперативний ответ!